# Replacing onClick with addEventListener

Tags: javascript, dom, onclick, dom-events

I'm trying to remove a script entirely to an external .js file and replace the `onClick` event with `addEventListener` in the external file. I can't get this to work:

http://jsfiddle.net/kjmatthews/DE26x/

My function is a little more complex, but this is essentially copied from http://jsfiddle.net/madBYK/UumUP/, linked from the [developer.mozilla.org page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener) on `element.addEventListener`.

Adding `onclick="return hidePurchased();"` to the `<input>` tag *does* work, so the problem is not with the `hidePurchased()` function.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`getElementsByName` returns a `NodeList`, which doesn't have `addEventListener` method, so you need to actually select the guy you are intending to bind the click listener to, by dereferencing the result

Try:

```
var foo = document.getElementsByName("hide")[0];
```

Working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/DE26x/9/

Answer (score 1):

Here your go. http://jsfiddle.net/DE26x/8/ From what I can tell, you only forget to select the first index of the foo array. It appears to be working now. Check it out and you will see that it has noshow class on the thing. I also added css to hide the noshow, so that you can see it working.